# Angular 404 on POST request

Tags: c#, angular, post

I am trying to pass credentials from Angular to C#, but Angular receives a 404. I am following a tutorial [from here](https://code-maze.com/authentication-aspnetcore-jwt-2/). Is there something wrong with how I'm passing the data? I'm certain the route is correct.

> OPTIONS http://localhost:52008/Account/GetJWT 404 (Not Found)
>
> login:1 Failed to load http://localhost:52008/Account/GetJWT: Response for preflight does not have HTTP ok status.

From the AccountController:

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

public async Task<IActionResult> GetJWT([FromBody]LoginModel user)
{
    myJWT m = new myJWT(user);
    return Ok(new { Token = m.token });
}
}
```

Angular code that is calling the Controller above:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html'
})
export class LoginComponent {
  invalidLogin: boolean;

  constructor(private router: Router, private http: HttpClient) { }

  login(form: NgForm) {
    let credentials = JSON.stringify(form.value);
    console.log(credentials);
    this.http.post("http://localhost:52008/Account/GetJWT", credentials, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      })
    }).subscribe(response => {
      let token = (<any>response).token;
      localStorage.setItem("jwt", token);
      this.invalidLogin = false;
      this.router.navigate(["/"]);
    }, err => {
      this.invalidLogin = true;
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Try `http://localhost:52008/Account/`. The C# method name is not part of the route.

Comment: @HansKilian Tried it with no success.... I'm pretty sure it is part of the route though. Do you have a source that says otherwise?

Comment: I couldn't find an AccountController in that example. But the routes there all start with `/api/`. Is that what you're missing? If not, then please add your routing setup to the code. I'm pretty sure that the error is in the routing since you're getting a 404 which would indicate that it can't figure out what method should handle the request.

Comment: @HansKilian, That makes sense. My Controller and route added, I dont quite follow the example on this one